# Change indexing of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to change the indexing of array for example. I have an array

```
$a = array("a","e","i","o","u");
echo $a[0]; //output a
```

It means this array has index (0,1,2,3,4)

Now I want to start my array from index 100 instead 0

Means array with index (100,200,300,400,500)

Comment: If this array is getting created dynamically,then you can easily assign the index you want in a loop.

Comment: Is there any system to this? Is is always a limited number of values? Is it dynamic? Can't you just type it by hand?

Comment: Is there an actual valid reason why you'd want this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to **declare** an array that way you should do:

```
$array = array(100 => 'a', 200 => 'b', 300 => 'c', 400 => 'd', 500 => 'e');
```

**Note** that if you add a new element to the `$array` in the shorter way (`$array[] = 'f'`) the key assigned will be `501`.

If you want to **convert** regular array indexes to *hundreds-based* ones you can do this:

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $temp[(($key + 1) * 100)] = $value;
}
$array = $temp;
```

But perhaps you don't really need to convert no array and instead access your current one this way:

```
$i = $hundredBasedIndex / 100 - 1;
echo $array[$i];
// or directly
echo $array[($hundredBasedIndex / 100 - 1)];
```

Comment: Thanks Jackflash for your answer.This is the first time when I asked question on internet. You really gave your answers in very right manner and explaining all the things. Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Other solution:

```
$a = array_combine(array(100, 200, 300, 400, 500), $a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply define a starting index and iterate over the array swapping the indexes.
Something like this -

```
$oldArray = array("a","e","i","o","u");  
$newArray = array();
$startIndex = 100;

foreach($oldArray AS $key => $value){
  $newArray[$startIndex] = $value;
  startIndex += 100;
}
```

Comment: except that `startIndex` has to be incremented by 100.

Comment: @ise - oops! Thanks for that! How embarrassing ;-) I'm still confused about the logic behind this behavior... I hope the OP has a justified reason to do this...

Answer (score 0):

just make an associative array with keys as indexes you want. for example :

```
$myArray = array(100=>"a",200=>"e",300=>"i",400=>"o",500=>"u");
```

then you call the values like:

```
echo $myArray[100] ;
```

**note:** do not put  `'100'=>"a"` instead of `100=>"a"`

Answer (score 0):

> $key = array(100, 200, 300, 400, 500);
>
> $b = array_combine($key, $a);

Answer (score -1):

Just create the array that way.

```
$myarray = array(
    100 => 'a',
    200 => 'b',
);
```

If you already have an array with that order, and want to multiply the keys by 100, you can do so in a loop (there are other ways, but...):

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

$newarray = array();
foreach($a as $key => $value)
    $newarray[100*($key+1)] = $value;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply change your array Like this:

```
$a = array(100 => "a", 200 => "e", 300 => "i", 400 => "o", 500 => "u");
```